# Home page reindexing error

Tags: magento2

I have a problem.
I built a site with magento 2.
The link is [www.mdinnova.it](http://www.mdinnova.it)
But from Google console there are redirection problems of the home page.  The error is 302.

If I send the command site:mdinnova.it the page is indexed, however, so I don't understand if Google has indexed the page correctly.

Furthermore, if I search on google.it for the keyword "metal detector" my site does not appear among the results.
I'm a little worried.  Is anyone able to solve?  thank you